# Do most major airlines measure the checked luggage for dimensions?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airlines

I'm trying to pick a suitcase for checked luggage, and I'm conflicted.

The most popular sizes I found online are 24 inch and 28 inch ones. 24 inch ones are well under the 62 inch linear limit. However, most of the 28 inch ones I've checked so far go over the 62 inch limit including the wheels.

So do most of the airlines not really care about a few inch excess as long as the weight is under the limit or people are just fine paying the extra fees as the 28 inch suitcases seem quite popular? Is there any pattern?

Comment: For checked baggage i have never seen them checking for strict dimensions as long as the weight is within limits and its still a reasonable sized luggage. An inch or 2 wont make a difference afaik

Comment: Typical 28" wheeled bags (around [this type](https://www.briggs-riley.com/shop/type/checked-luggage/baseline-large-expandable-upright-u128cx) from numerous manufacturers and at different prices) I've seen are around 28x18x12 or so, plus or minus an inch or two, to keep you within the 62" limit. I agree that airlines aren't usually strict about size limits at all, but most of the popular 28" bags I see shouldn't pose any issue.

Comment: The 28 inch figure for the case typically goes up to 30 inches with the wheel and possible 1/2 or 1 inch more for the non-moving handle as well, so going with the case dimension I'd be ok but the overall dimension typically end up around 63-65 inches for brands such as Samsonite and Amazonbasics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to prove a negative (i.e. that airlines *never* check), but I've never seen it happen. A couple of commenters have suggested they've never seen it either.

I have a 30 inch suitcase whose dimensions add up to 66 inches, if you include the wheels. There's never been any sort of a problem, and I've seen bigger suitcases used by others with no problems either.

As long as you stick with a typical wheeled suitcase I think you'll be fine. They might be more likely to measure the great big aluminium boxes I've seen a few people travelling with.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware it's hard to prove. Some airlines such as Southwest Airlines explicitly state they don't include wheels and handles(so just the case) which is under 62 but I doubt anybody bothers to check for popular suitcase sizes. I saw another relevant question on the site where people claimed the airlines are getting strict about enforcing the dimension rules for checked luggage, but I thought they were being overly cautious.